# Unexpected behaviour when sorting a List<String>

Tags: c#, list, linq, cultureinfo

If I try to sort a list of strings by:

```
List<String> lstStrings = new List<string>();

String s1 = "KÜHLSCHRANK";
String s2 = "KUHLSCHRANK";
int i = s1.CompareTo(s2);   // returns 1
int j = s2.CompareTo(s1);   // return -1 

i = StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare(s1, s2); // returns 1
j = StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare(s2, s1); // returns -1

lstStrings.Add("KÜHLSCHRANK1");
lstStrings.Add("KUTTER");
lstStrings.Add("KUHLSCHRANK2");
lstStrings.Add("KÜHLSCHRANK3");

var lstStrings1 = lstStrings.OrderBy(y => y).ToList();
var lstStrings2 = lstStrings.OrderBy(y => y, StringComparer.InvariantCulture).ToList();
var lstStrings3 = lstStrings.OrderBy(y => y, StringComparer.CurrentCulture).ToList();
var lstStrings4 = lstStrings.OrderBy(y => y, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToList();
```

I get the following results in *lstStrings1*, *lstStrings2* AND *lstStrings3*:

```
    [0] "KÜHLSCHRANK1"
    [1] "KUHLSCHRANK2"
    [2] "KÜHLSCHRANK3"
    [3] "KUTTER"
```

Only my *lstStrings4* shows the result I expected:

```
    [0] "KUHLSCHRANK2"  
    [1] "KUTTER"    
    [2] "KÜHLSCHRANK1"
    [3] "KÜHLSCHRANK3"
```

Could anyone explain why the german 'Ü' is threaded like the normal 'U' by Default?

Why doesn't the OrderBy using the StringComparer.InvariantCulture care about the results of the `StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare(s1, s2)` (which would mean the List is Ordered like my lstStrings4 in previous sample)?

Is there any way to change this "default behaviour"?

Added:
if i Append the numbers to the Strings, the results of the Compare-Methods Change:

```
        String s1 = "KÜHLSCHRANK1";
        String s2 = "KUHLSCHRANK2";
        int i = s1.CompareTo(s2);   // returns -1
        int j = s2.CompareTo(s1);   // return 1 

        i = StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare(s1, s2); // returns -1
        j = StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare(s2, s1); // returns 1
```

So i don't even understand, why my first test without numbers does not return zero on each Compare...

2nd Add:
On SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @tableDE TABLE (strName NVARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE German_PhoneBook_CI_AI)

INSERT INTO @tableDE (strName)
SELECT e FROM (VALUES('KUHLSCHRANK1'), ('KÜHLSCHRANK2')) f(e)

SELECT * FROM @tableDE ORDER BY strName
```

gives as result:

```
KÜHLSCHRANK2
KUHLSCHRANK1
```

As a result:
If i do an `OrderBy` in LinqToSql and get the result into a List, 
a new `OrderBy`on the List variable, even with the same Parameters, would change the order of elements.

Comment: Your initial comparisons aren't terribly useful as those strings are never present in the sorted list. I suggest you try comparing "KÜHLSCHRANK1" and "KUHLSCHRANK2" instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Added the requested example

Comment: Right, so all the sorting part is now completely irrelevant, and should be removed.

Comment: (I suspect the answer is "the umlaut is only relevant in a tie-break" or similar)

Comment: Overall string comparisons summarized here (added comparison by German culture): https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vg9xL2. Check if the results are right there.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto result of lstStrings5 is also wrong

Comment: @m.plumbohm Well, I think it's also strange that German culture `StringComparer` outputting same value as `lstStrings1` to `lstStrings3`. You've expected comparing umlauts with standard "u" before numbers, haven't you?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto You are right. In German, it is a totally different letter, so it is not only a matter pronounciation like it would be in french for example ('e' and 'é')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you answer on why ordinal gives you the result you the "expected". According to the documentation of `StringComparer.Ordinal`

> The StringComparer returned by the Ordinal property performs a simple byte comparison that is independent of language. This is most appropriate when comparing strings that are generated programmatically or when comparing case-sensitive resources such as passwords.

So `U` is `0x55` and `Ü` is `0x220`. So this sorts your different U's out. But there is a problem with this, let's say you add the word `KËTTER` (probably not an actual german word, but it is for demostrative purposes). Your list will be organized as such:

```
[0] "KUHLSCHRANK2"
[1] "KUTTER"
[2] "KËTTER"
[3] "KÜHLSCHRANK1"
[4] "KÜHLSCHRANK3"
```

As you can see the `Ë` falls between your two different U's, and that is because `Ë` has the unicode of `0x203`, and `55<203<220` means `U<Ë<Ü`.

So if your goal is sort on letters, and then by the accent of the letter, I would advise against using Ordinal.

Now, i can't leave comments, but are you sure you want to organize by letters then sort on the accent of the letters. I haven't seen dictionaries make a difference between an accented letter and the normal counterpart, and that is probably why the culture dependent sorts do not give the result you require.

added:
 I've added a couple more cases to your test, so now the full list of unsorted looks a little like this

```
[0] "KÜHLSCHRANK1"
[1] "KUHLSCHRANK1"
[2] "KUTTER"
[3] "KUHLSCHRANK2"
[4] "KÜHLSCHRANK2"
[5] "KÜHLSCHRANK3"
[6] "KËTTER"
```

the invariantCulture and current Culture yeild the same results, and that is:

```
[0] "KËTTER"
[1] "KUHLSCHRANK1"
[2] "KÜHLSCHRANK1"
[3] "KUHLSCHRANK2"
[4] "KÜHLSCHRANK2"
[5] "KÜHLSCHRANK3"
[6] "KUTTER"
```

So this demostrates that only on a complete match (ignoring the accents) do the accents come into play. And the unaccented has priority.

2nd add:

According to wikipedia

> Ü, or ü, is a character that typically represents a close front rounded vowel [y]. It is classified as a separate letter in several extended Latin alphabets (including Azeri, Estonian, Hungarian and Turkish), but as the letter U with an umlaut/diaeresis in others such as Catalan, French, Galician, German, Occitan and Spanish.

So in german, the umlaut is not a seperate letter, but just an accent, if you were to use turkish culture instead, it would be treated as a seperate letter.
So the result when the culture is turkish is:

```
[0] "KËTTER"
[1] "KUHLSCHRANK1"
[2] "KUHLSCHRANK2"
[3] "KUTTER"
[4] "KÜHLSCHRANK1"
[5] "KÜHLSCHRANK2"
[6] "KÜHLSCHRANK3"
```

this yeilds the result I believe you wanted. Just this would be the wrong culture for your words.

Response to the comment:

As you noted, the phone book does organize as you want, and after some digging, there are two sorting algorthims used by .net for german. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7zyyk0c.aspx)
When using the phone book sorting algorthim it yeilds the results:

```
[0] "KËTTER"
[1] "KÜHLSCHRANK1"
[2] "KÜHLSCHRANK2"
[3] "KÜHLSCHRANK3"
[4] "KUHLSCHRANK1"
[5] "KUHLSCHRANK2"
[6] "KUTTER"
```

in order to use the phonebook sorting algorithm use the following:

```
var germanPhone=new CultureInfo(0x00010407);
StringComparer germanPhoneICComp = StringComparer.Create(germanPhone, true);\\set to false if caps are important to you
var lstStrings7 = lstStrings.OrderBy(y => y, germanPhoneICComp).ToList();
```

Comment: Can't agree to the wikipedia article. Just tested in on SQLServer for example. The Collation German_PhoneBook_100_CI_AI threats it as separate letters.

Comment: hey, I updated my answer to show how to sort as the german phone book does. My apologies for taking so long.

Comment: Thanks for your help